# Axios Error while connecting react-native to node.js

Tags: node.js, react-native, axios

I've made an axios HTTP request in the following function:

```
const uploadImage = async () => {
    try {
      const { fileUri } = state;
  
      if (!fileUri) {
        console.log('Please select an image first.');
        return;
      }
  
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('image', {
        uri: fileUri,
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        name: 'image.jpg',
      });
  
      // Replace 'YOUR_BACKEND_API_URL' with your actual backend API endpoint
      const response = await axios.post('http://your-server-ip/upload', formData);
  
      console.log('Image uploaded successfully:', response.data);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error('Error uploading image:', error);
  
      if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
        // AxiosError is a specific type for Axios errors
        console.error('Axios response data:', (error as AxiosError).response?.data);
        console.error('Axios response status:', (error as AxiosError).response?.status);
        console.error('Axios response headers:', (error as AxiosError).response?.headers);
      } else {
        // Handle non-Axios errors
        console.error('Non-Axios error message:', error.message);
      }
    }
  };
```

The backend `index.js` code goes like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors'); // Import the cors middleware

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

// Set up storage for multer
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'files/'); // Destination folder for uploaded files
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

// Enable CORS using the cors middleware
app.use(cors());

// Define a route for image uploads
app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  try {
    const filePath = req.file.path;
    console.log('Image uploaded:', filePath);
    res.json({ success: true, filePath });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error uploading image:', error.message);
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

I'm getting the following error while trying to hit the `/upload` api:

`ERROR  Error uploading image: [AxiosError: Network Error]`

`ERROR  Axios response data: undefined`

`ERROR  Axios response status: undefined`

`ERROR  Axios response headers: undefined`

I'm using USB debugging to test the app on my physical device.
Please help me in resolving the issue.

I tried asking ChatGPT and read some docs, but still the issue is unresolved.